# how to add a logo on top of texture

Tags: modeling

I created a t shirt and I applied normal maps and displacements to make it look more like a cotton but what i wanna do now is i wanna add a logo on the chest. How can I do it? Thank you alot for any response. Pictures below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It did not work out exactly as you wanted it to, but it's a bit close to what you want.
as if to blend these two pictures together. I just mixed you with your picture

I linked it in the editor

[image]

[image: the result is as below]

Comment: Please explain the logic behind the node setup you are using.